# Joining 3 Tables on Multiple Fields

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to join 3 tables in order to get the following results:

```
   Table_A:
    Customer   Product     Div_Num      Importance
    C1          P1          X            .5
```

```
   Table_B:
    Div_Num         Div_Name
    X               Arizona
```

```
    **Table_C:**
    *Customer   Product     Sales*
    C1      P1      15
    C1      P1      20
```

```
    **Desired Results:**
    *Customer   Product     Div_Name    Importance  Sum(Sales)*
    C1          P1          Arizona     .5          35
```

```
   Select Table_A.Customer, Table_A.Product, Table_B.Div_Name, Table_A.Importance, sum(Table_C.Sales)
    From Table_A
      Inner Join Table_B
        On Table_A.Div_Num = Table_B.Div_Num
      Inner Join Table_C
        On Table_A.Customer = Table_C.Customer And Table_A.Product = Table_C.Product
    Where Table_A.Product IN ('P1', 'P2', 'P3')
```

I am getting Error 42S02(29): relation does not exist

Comment: Try simplifying your query and gradually add complexity until you hit the error, so you can see what is causing it.  For example, start with SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE Table_A.Product IN (P1, P2, P3).  If that works, add in the join to Table_B, and so on.

Comment: I should have mentioned the error comes in when I add the 2nd join with the sum term. Everything else was working fine before I put that in

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f07e/2)

You forgot the `GROUP BY`

```
Select Table_A.Customer, Table_A.Product, Table_B.Div_Name, Table_A.Importance, sum(Table_C.Sales)
From Table_A
  Inner Join Table_B
    On Table_A.Div_Num = Table_B.Div_Num
  Inner Join Table_C
    On Table_A.Customer = Table_C.Customer And Table_A.Product = Table_C.Product
Where Table_A.Product IN ('P1', 'P2', 'P3')
GROUP BY Table_A.Customer, Table_A.Product, Table_B.Div_Name, Table_A.Importance
```

Comment: My mistake, the original code has the single quotes in it (I edited it in). The error is actually coming in after I add the 2nd join

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that sum is a group by term. You can't have it unless you have a group by to create the roll up that you're going to sum. You probably need:

```
 group by Table_A.Customer, Table_A.Product, Table_B.Div_Name, Table_A.Importance
```